# Html.BeginForm Vs Form - which is better and why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC & C# and just looking at doing a form on my website.

I see I can use either html.beginform, or just a standard html .
It seems that everyone on the net is using html.beginform, but I can't understand the advantage. It seems to me that using beginform is just extra work for the server to render the html.

Comment: There's no better or worse, they server different purposes. `Html.BeginForm` will render `<form></form>` in the final HTML. You can pass parameters to `Html.BeginForm` that have special meaning, compared to if you did it manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Asp.Net MVC BeginForm is aware of routes defined in the RouteConfig. The ASP.NET Routing module is responsible for mapping incoming browser requests to particular MVC controller actions.

The BeginForm HTML helper asks the routing engine how to reach the action of the Controller. Behind the scenes it uses the method named GetVirtualPath on the Routes property exposed by RouteTable — that’s where your web application registered all its routes in global.asax

So, in future, even if you have changed mapping of routes for that controller and action, it will correctly set action of form tag in html.

Similar case for other helpers like Html.ActionLink, it would generate hyperlinks that are aware of routes defined.

Answer (score -1):

html.beginform will wrap your HTML content for you within the curly braces, also its helps you specify a "Controller" and Action "Easily".

```
Html.beginform("Action", "Controller", "Method") {
  // HTML controls here
} // Simulates a </form> tag
```

if you were to use the plain FORM tag then you have to hard code the URL and close the FORM tag yourself.

as far as performance is concerned, there is no difference. its all about personal preference.